# FileNot FoundError:fluidsynth

Tags: python-3.x

I just want to convert my midi files to mp3 by using `midi2audio`, i use this code:

```
----------
from midi2audio import FluidSynth

FluidSynth().midi_to_audio('test.mid','test.mp3')


---------- or

from midi2audio import FluidSynth

FluidSynth().play_midi('test.mid')
```

but i got the same result:

```
----------


/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/bin/python3.6 /Users/blake/Desktop/Bsmart_music/test/t_p/1.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/blake/Desktop/Bsmart_music/test/t_p/1.py", line 5, in <module>
    FluidSynth().play_midi('test.mid')
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/midi2audio.py", line 49, in play_midi
    subprocess.call(['fluidsynth', '-i', self.sound_font, midi_file, '-r', str(self.sample_rate)])
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/subprocess.py", line 267, in call
    with Popen(*popenargs, **kwargs) as p:
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/subprocess.py", line 709, in __init__
    restore_signals, start_new_session)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/subprocess.py", line 1344, in _execute_child
    raise child_exception_type(errno_num, err_msg, err_filename)
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'fluidsynth': 'fluidsynth'

Process finished with exit code 1


----------
```

So, i try to copy the fold "fluidsynth" to "midi2audio", but it still doesn't work. I have installed both midi2audio and fluidsynth, who knows what happened?

Answer (score 1):

you must copy "fluidsynth" in some folder pointed by your PATH environ variable
( type "echo $PATH" in terminal app to see what is registered actually ).

On unix-like systems python will usually find fluidsynth located at /usr/bin/fluidsynth ( as /usr/bin is listed in the PATH ). on Os X things are not much different any documentation should fit. A common practice is to use /usr/local/bin folder for adding custom programs.

Comment: Thanks a lot, if wanna to convert musicxml to mp3 directly with python3, how could i do!

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you should install fluidsynth first

for ubuntu:

```
sudo apt-get install fluidsynth
```